# Laravel 9 + vite.js + jquery + bootstrap ain't easily working out of the box

Tags: jquery, laravel, tooltip, popover, vite

For the last couple of hours, I struggled to get jquery working AND bootstrap popover and tooltip to work within blade files in laravel 9 on vite.js. Btw, I'm new on Laravel.

I have searched a lot for answers but there was nothing specific anywhere. So I finally ended finding a solution from various pieces of code I've found.

Considering you already have a vite.js server running on Laravel 9 and that you have installed jquery and bootstrap

```
npm install jquery
npm install bootstrap
```

First, if you want jquery to works, you have to declare the script tag with type="module" as below:

```
<script type="module">
    $('#test').addClass('fun');    
</script>
```

Here is how you can get popover and tooltip working:

In resources/js/bootstrap.js

```
import $ from "jquery";
window.$ = $;

import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
window.bootstrap = bootstrap;
```

In your file.blade.php, here is how to enable tooltip globally in your page

```
<script type="module">
    $(function () {
         var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
         var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
         return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
    })
});
```

Is this the correct way to implement tooltips and popovers within Laravel vite.js blade file?